# Changing value in a array and display

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, indexing

Hi I wrote a code that supposed display the name of each person and then able to select which ever person I pick, then it display they grade and let me able to change it. I got it to display they grade but I don't know how to change that persons grade value only, instead it changes every persons grade and displays it how do I change it? So it displays the change of that one person only? and add whatever value I want to it? And how do I display the changed value next to the persons name? If you could help me I be very thank full.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int selection;
        do
        {
            String[] A = { "Tim", "Jhon", "Sam", "Derp"};
            int[] B = { 90, 89, 60, 40 };
            DisplayMenu();
            Console.Write("Enter you selection: ");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out selection);
            switch (selection)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine(
            "{0}  ", B[0]);
                    AddToGrade(B);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine(
            "{0}  ", B[1]);
                    AddToGrade(B);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine(
            "{0}  ", B[2]);
                    AddToGrade(B);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine(
            "{0}  ", B[3]);
                    AddToGrade(B);
                    break;
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        } while (selection != 4);

    }
    static void DisplayMenu()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Select a student 1-4");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Time");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Jhon");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Sam");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Derp");
    }
    static void AddToGrade(int[] array)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Input New Value: ");
        int newValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] += newValue;
            Console.Write("New Grade: {0}", array[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since C# is an Object Oriented language, you should think about creating a Person or Student class.

Comment: I totally agree with Mert, although I wrote an answer, you should take this comment into account while fixing your code.

Comment: @Ofiris I will thanks for the input and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AddToGrade` should accept `index` representing the grade to change.

```
static void AddToGrade(int[] array ,int index)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Input New Value: ");
     int newValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
     array[index] += newValue;
     Console.Write("New Grade: {0}", array[index]);
}
```

And after your switch (before the `Console.ReadKey();`) just call this:

```
AddToGrade(B, selection - 1);
```

Moreover, you should use more functions to make your code robust and elegant,
e.g. (That example will also alliw you to keep the formatting in a single place)

```
static void DisplayNameGrade(int index, String[] A, int[] B)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Grade: {1}", A[index], B[index])
}
```

**Generally, you should learn the basic concepts of [Object Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), and design your code with classes, members and functions.**

Comment: Hmmm I get a blue error code at the array[i] it doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: Should be `array[index]`

Comment: and do I put DisplayNameGrade at my case or do I add something else to it? sorry im still fairly new to C#.

Comment: You can either make A and B globals, or to pass them as the function arguments, I edited my post.

Comment: Yeah I just did that since I saw that it was missing.